# SparkSQL with ScalaPB: Error while skipping proto fields while converting from DataFrame to proto dataset

Tags: apache-spark, protobuf-net, scalapb

I have the following proto message, that needs to be written through Spark using ScalaPB:

```
message EnforcementData
{
  required int32 id = 1;
  required int32 source = 2;
  required int32 flagsEnforceOption = 4;
  required int32 categoryEnforceOption = 5;

  optional TypeA a= 100;
  optional TypeB b= 101;
}
```

`TypeA` and `TypeB` are child classes of `EnforcementData` on the receiver side, which uses protobuf-net to deserialize the same.

Now, my Spark dataframe can either have column a or column b. Suppose, df is my dataframe, I call the following:

- `df.withColumn(b, null).as[EnforcementData].map(_.toByteArray)` for TypeA messages
- `df.withColumn(a, null).as[EnforcementData].map(_.toByteArray)` for TypeB messages

But the receiver which deserializes the message using protobuf-net, throws StackOverflow exception. I also tried passing a dummy case class instead of null and still it does not seem to work.

Please let me know how to handle this?

Comment: The fact that you get a StackOverflow with protobuf-net indicates that there isn't enough information here to tell what the problem is - we don't see the serialization and deserialization calls. My best guess is that the protobuf-net classes don't match the proto file. But the problem could also be in the code that transmits or receives the bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by reconstructing the case class and explicitly skipping the optional child class fields. i.e.

```
 //for TypeA messages,

 df.withColumn(b, null)
   .as[EnforcementData]
   .map{case EnforcementData(id, source, flag, cat, a, _) => EnforcementData(id, source, flag, cat, a = a) 
   } 

 //for TypeB messages,    

 df.withColumn(s, null)
   .as[EnforcementData]
   .map{case EnforcementData(id, source, flag, cat, _, b) => EnforcementData(id, source, flag, cat, b = b) 
    }
```